# Lack of brackets in interpretation haskell function type

Tags: haskell

New to haskell, I felt like the `:t` lacks brackets for me to properly understand a function type

like this one:

```
Prelude> :info flip
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

I could say: `flip` is taking one function and returning another function by bracketing like this:

```
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> (b -> a -> c)
```

or I could say `flip` is taking one function and `b` and `a` and returning elements `c`

for quite a few functions types I had this feeling, I guess there must be some rules to eliminate this ambiguity

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, this isn't an ambiguity, it is a feature!

Take, for instance, the plus operator, (+).  It has type

```
(+)::Num a=>a->a->a
```

Which you can think of as a function which takes two numbers, and returns a third.

```
number 
       \
          ----> number
       /
number
```

You use this like this-

```
 (+) 1 2 (-- evaluates to 3)
 or
 1 + 2 (-- evaluates to 3)
```

*or*, you can use it as

```
(+)::Num a=>a->(a->a)
```

which takes one number, and outputs a full function, whose domain and range are each a number, ie `Num a=>a->a`.

```
number ------> <function>
```

for instance

```
(+) 1 (-- evaluates to incrementorFunc)
....also written as (+ 1)
```

where `incrementorFunc` is the function that adds one to a number (ie `incrementorFunc = \x -> 1+x`).

You can now pass this function around to be used elsewhere in the code.

This duality is inherently built into all functions, and so no bracket is needed in the type description.  This feature is one Haskells greatest strengths.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by `Num a=>(a->a)->a`.  Do you mean `Num a=>(a,a)->a`, which it sortof is...

Comment: @luqui- You are correct, I am being sloppy....  And you are correct about what I basically meant.  Give me a few secs and I will reword parts of this.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the brackets because there is no difference between the two.

Purists would say that all Haskell functions take exactly one argument. There are no multiple argument functions. For instance:

```
map f [1..10]
```

is interpreted as:

```
(map f) [1..10]
```

i.e., `map` is applied with argument `f` and the result is applied with argument `[1..10]`.

This interpretation is what makes automatic currying work in Haskell. In a sense currying is an illusion in Haskell - i.e. we see `map f` and we see a curried form of `map` since there is only one argument. In reality `map` only takes one argument, so `map f` is fully applied.